# Android Marshmallow storage mounting

Tags: android, storage, android-6.0-marshmallow, mount

I have a two questions on Android Marshmallow storage mounting.

1. In logcat during system startup I obtained follow messages:

   MountService: No primary storage defined yet; hacking together a stub
   MountService: No primary storage defined yet; hacking together a stub
   MountService: No primary storage mounted!

Despite on this all mounting points /system /data /cache /sdcard is mounted and system successfully starting up. 
What actually means primary storage for Android Marshmallow?

2. Whats "voldmanaged" flag in fstab.hardware actually means?

For example, in this configuration, mounting occcurs successfully.

```
/dev/block/sdd2      /sdcard  ext4  noatime,nosuid,nodev,barrier=1,nomblk_io_submit   wait,check
```

But when I try to add "voldmanaged" flag, mounting is not occurs.

```
/dev/block/sdd2      /sdcard  ext4  noatime,nosuid,nodev,barrier=1,nomblk_io_submit   wait,check,voldmanaged=sdcard:auto
```

Is required some additional actions (for example, emit some broadcast intent) for mounting with "voldmanaged"?